# How to add a (windows readable) backup disk to Netgear ReadyNAS?

Tags: backup, nas, compatibility, readynas

So we have this [ReadyNAS appliance](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/storage/prosumer/RND4210.aspx) with 2x1TB disks in Netgear X-RAID (read: mirrored), two empty disk bays and all three usb ports unused.

We'd like to add another 1TB disk to the NAS and schedule backups from the NAS to that disk, but we also want that disk to be readable by a normal PC if the NAS implodes or whatever, and [the documentation](http://www.readynas.com/download/documentation/UM/ReadyNAS_UM_19Nov07.pdf) isn't really clear on this point.

Can I add an NTFS-formatted USB disk and backup on that, so I'll be able to read it later using a standard PC?

Does the same applies if I add the backup disk in one of the free internal bays instead of attaching it to a USB port?

Comment: So you'd like to be able to plug the disks into a computer directly for data recovery if the NAS fails?

Comment: More or less. Not the actual disks where the NAS does its work (the 2x1TB in X-RAID), but the backup disk I'm gonna buy and add.